# Как добавить надпись под ось matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

Была необходимость создать автоматически собираемый отчёт и столкнулся с проблемой: в графиках под осью X нужно ставить значение даты. Однако, просто вставив туда массив с датой, выходит ошибка: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Jan 03:00:02'`

Если пишу явное преобразование `plt.plot(str(gprs_data), gx1)` тогда ошибка такая: `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (2,)`

Смотрел некоторые посты, где предлагается замена значений оси на некоторые строки, но это не подходит, ибо количество точек и дата меняются. Вот часть кода:

```
    fig = plt.figure()  # графики изменения проекций ускорения по 3 осям
plt.subplot(321)
plt.plot(str(x), y)

plt.title('Акселерометр(x)')
plt.xticks(fontsize='6',rotation= 60)
plt.yticks(fontsize='10')
plt.grid()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь вместо чисел вставить строки, поэтому он и ругается

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Jan 03:00:02'.

Потом вы пытаетесь сделать примерно то же самое и строить рисунок. По идее вам нужно либо переводить эти даты в секунды, а потом меткам на оси в секундах сопоставлять даты. Либо использовать библиотеку pandas для работы с временными рядами.